# Smarty framework if/else statement always goes to the "if" part

Tags: php, web, smarty

On a certain page of my website (that uses PHP and the smarty templating framework), I have a map of the world on which I display information. I propose several types of color pallet to the user in order to help with the visibility of the information displayed. Each time the user changes his selection of color pallet, I reload the page by changing a parameter in the URL. For example,

```
www.mywebsite.com/home.php?id=norm_d_maps&mpn=norms&FromMonth=05&FromDay=16&v=1&**palette=1**&labels=0&intervals=10&min=&max=&lon=-7836935.6349316&lat=6193233.778916&zoom=5
```

will become

```
www.mywebsite.com/home.php?id=norm_d_maps&mpn=norms&FromMonth=05&FromDay=16&v=1&**palette=2**&labels=0&intervals=10&min=&max=&lon=-7836935.6349316&lat=6193233.778916&zoom=5
```

In order to catch that change, as mentioned earlier, I reload the page with the new URL and catch each of its parameters and redisplay the page like follows:

```
$page = Map::fromId('468BE166-A38D-43C9-B61B-3AA72BC50210');

echo '<h1>' . fct_traduire('txt_norm_d_maps') . '</h1>';

$page->tplEngine->assign('LANGUAGE', $session->lang);
$page->tplEngine->assign('LOGGED_IN', $session->isLoggedIn());
$page->tplEngine->assign('MENU', generate_navigation( $GLOBALS['g_section'] ));
**$page->tplEngine->assign('PALETTE', $_GET['palette']);**
$page->tplEngine->assign('MIN', $_GET['min']);
$page->tplEngine->assign('MAX', $_GET['max']);
$page->openlayers_DailyNormalsAndExtremes($_GET['FromMonth'], $_GET['FromDay'], $_GET['v'], $_GET['labels'], $_GET['palette'], $_GET['intervals'], $_GET['lon'], $_GET['lat'], $_GET['zoom'], $_GET['clustered'], $_GET['min'], $_GET['max']);
$page->tplEngine->display('extends:map_layout.html|' . $page->display());
```

The part of map_layout.html in which I use those options has the following structure:

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                **{if $PALETTE == 1}**
                <td with a certain background color>
                **{else}**
                <td with another background color>
                **{/if}**
                ...
            </tr>
            ...
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, even if the palette parameter in the URL is 2, the td node has the background color of the first if condition each time (so it is as if palette == 1 when it is actually == 2). Later in my code, I use the MIN and MAX parameters and they seem to change properly each time I reload the page with the new values for them that the user chose.

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: I just displayed the value of the palette, min and max parameters on my webpage, and while the min and max are indeed the good values the user chose, the palette parameter is "Palette" instead of being 1 or 2 or anything other integer the user chooses.. What could cause this?

Comment: `var_dump($_GET['palette'])` in the controller, before assigning

Comment: @Rudie I get the following output: string(1) "2". Unfortunately, like I have written in the edit of my post, the value of the variable in the html file is "Palette". Why is that? Shouldn't it be "2" like the dump shows?

Comment: Oh, right, my bad. That's weird indeed. What if you change the name to `PALETTEx` or something? Does it keep that? `PALETTE` might be overwritten later...

Comment: @Rudie Yep, that was it. I just started working on that project 2 days ago and am not familiar with all the code yet, so I guess that variable name was already taken and as such was overwritten somewhere else in the process. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was that the variable `PALETTE` was already taken by the framework and/or somewhere else in the code. A simple variable rename fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You should double check all of your assignments. Everything seems to be ok with your code.
You should also check value of `$_GET['palette']` before assigning it to Smarty.

With simple code:

in PHP:

```
$smarty->assign('PALETTE', $_GET['palette']);

$smarty->display('index.tpl');
```

everything works fine:

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                {if $PALETTE == 1}
                <td with a certain background color>
                PALETTE 1
                {else}
                PALETTE 2
                <td with another background color>
                {/if}
                ...
            </tr>
            ...
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to avoid looping data logic, and get the same result, is to use CSS classes. For example:

```
<style>
.palette_unknown { background-color: crimson; } /* if you see red, problem */
.palette_1 { background-color: orange; }
.palette_2 { background-color: limegreen; }
</style>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="palette_{$palette|default:'unknown'}">...</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The general idea behind avoiding logic blocks is that you never have to revise logic to update a style. You can use a bunch of different data properties to intelligently highlight a data table, or other elements.

Doing things this way would isolate your problem to your PHP file: the assignment is not there.

In the event that your data key/value/etc contains inconvenient symbols that wouldn't work for CSS class names, just take an md5 of the data. For example, if your `$palette` happens to contain multiple lines such as `"Hello this is a palette\n\nSecond sentence underneath it."` you can do:

```
<td class="palette_{$palette|default:'unknown'|md5}">...</td>
```

Defining those styles  is a few extra steps, but, won't fail. Or at least it'll degrade gracefully.

```
<style>
.palette_ad921d60486366258809553a3db49a4a { color: crimson } /* red = bad :/ */
.palette_adaaa186794a24c85f591464121c0f7e { color: orange } /* big sentence */
</style>
```

Remember to prefix all CSS classes with something, as md5 hashes can begin with numbers.